# Reduction from vertex-cover to system of quadratic equations

Tags: np-hard, polynomial-time-reductions, vertex-cover

Define
$$\text{SQE}=\{S\ |\ S\ \text{is a system of quadratic equations with real solutions}\}$$
and
$$\text{VC}=\{G\ |\ G\ \text{is a simple undirected graph with a vertex cover}\ \leq k\}$$

I am trying to prove that SQE is NP-hard via the reduction $VC\leq_P SQE$.

**My attempt:**

Given a $G=(V,E)$, we want to construct some system of quadratic equations $S$, such that $G\in VC$ if and only if $S$ has real solutions.

For each $u\in V$ introduce the variable $x_u$. We want $x_u=1$ represent vertex $u$ being in the vertex cover and $x_u=0$ to represent it is not. How can we capture, using a quadratic equation, the fact that in a vertex-cover every edge is covered?

For each edge $\{u,v\}\in E$ we introduce the following inequality.
$$x_u + x_v \geq 1$$
However, we are not allowed inequalities. With some thought I came up with the following to replace the inequality.
$$x_u+x_v-x_ux_v=1$$
This is equal to $1$ if and only if either $u$ or $v$ or both are in the vertex-cover.

However, the domain for an $x_u$ is the reals, but we want to operate in $\{0,1\}$, so that each vertex is either chosen or not. Therefore, we can introduce for each $v\in V$ the following equation
$$x_v^2 = x_v$$
which has solutions $0$ or $1$ only.

Now we just need to limit the number of vertices in the vertex-cover to $\leq k$. Using an inequality this is written $\sum_{u\in V}{x_u}\leq k$. I now need some quadratic function $f(x_{u_1}, x_{u_2}, ..., x_{u_n}) = c$ if and only if $\sum_{u\in V}{x_u}\leq k$. But I can't figure out what it should look like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add $k$ Boolean variables $z_1,\ldots,z_k$ and the constraint $\sum_{u \in V} x_u + \sum_{i=1}^k z_i = k$.

(Optimization: add $\ell = \lceil \log_2 k \rceil$ Boolean variables $w_1,\ldots,w_\ell$ and the constraint $\sum_{u \in V} x_u + \sum_{j=1}^\ell 2^{j-1} w_j = k$.)

Comment: Ohhh. I am a dummy haha. Thank you.